# Existence of a positive function satisfying a integration property

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

This is related to a question I asked in mathoverflow, which hasn't been answered yet.

Does there exist a measurable(preferably $C^1$) function $ g: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^+ $, so that $$ \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(t)g(x-t)\sqrt{e^{2t}+e^{2(x-t)}} dt $$ is finite and independent of $ x $ where $ x\in \mathbb{R} $?

Comment: Just a couple of points.If we derive wrt to $x$ under the integration sign we get $$\int _{-\infty}^\infty g(t)\sqrt{e^{2t} + e^{2(x-t)}}\left[g'(x-t)(e^{2t} + e^{2(x-t)}) + g(x-t)e^{2(x-t)}\right] dt = 0$$. First of all we can't make the integrand equal to $0$ (setting it equal to $0$ yields a ODE whose result is $g(x-t) = \frac A{\sqrt{e^{2t} + e^{2(x-t)}}}$ which is not admissable as $g(t)$ would depend on $x$. So the integrand must alternate sign, but the only thing that could be negative there is $g'(x-t)$, that is $g'$ must be negative in some interval and g cannot be (always) increasing

Comment: I know it doesn't really help a lot but better than nothing :/

Comment: I also have been trying it this way, but haven't got anything yet.

Answer (score 0):

I have obtained a result that is almost constant.

Maybe it is not what you are looking for, but it worth examining it. Let us consider $$g(t)=\begin{cases} 1/\sqrt{t}&\text{if} \ t>0\\0&otherwise \end{cases}$$

$$f(x):=\int\limits_{0}^{x} \dfrac{1}{(t(x-t))^{1/2}}\sqrt{e^{2t}+e^{2(x-t)}} dt$$

takes its values between 11.8 and 12.7 (relative error approx. 3%). Taking a fourth root (power $1/4$ instead of $1/2$) gives a similar approximation (relative error $4\%$)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In this example, if you take $ x<0 $, then the integral will be 0. But if the integral is almost constant on the whole real line, I think I can use it.